# How could I connect Power BI to Oracle Cloud Analitics?

Tags: oracle, powerbi, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-analytics

I would like to see how to connect to Oracle Cloud with Power Bi, I have already tried the beta connector and the connector with the Oracle Client but I do not have direct access to the database (nor will I have from what I was told) so I would like to see if it is possible connect with data extractor or connect with cloud storage service.

Connect to Oracle Coud to be able to extract the reports, reports that have already been created in Oracle or the information structure that still needs to replicate what was done in "Oracle Analytics"

Connect from "Oracle Business Intelligence Cloud Connector Console" or some other option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could I connect Power BI to Oracle Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77368004/how-could-i-connect-power-bi-to-oracle-cloud)

Comment: I thought Power BI required direct access to the database. If you don't have that, I'm not sure there is any way to use that tool. Oracle Analytics or Business Intelligence will generate finished reports *instead* of using Power BI, not datasets for use in other tools. To get access to those, or to exported datasets you could ingest to Power BI, you'll have to work with whoever is administering the cloud tenancy and/or database. No one here can answer questions that will be specific to that tenancy.